# VB6 - Lua Integration

Tags: scripting, vb6, lua

I'm wondering if anyone has any tips for integrating Lua and VB6. I am running a small Online RPG that would be awesome to add some scripting to.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it is doable. I once did it for Lua 5.0.2 but I can't find the files. Among the options you have, you can:

- Wrap Lua in a COM dll exposing the Lua API, so in VB you can add a reference to it.
- Build your custom Lua version, using the __stdcall calling convention, so you can use Declare in VB to import the needed Lua functions. Writing a Type Library will ease a lot the integration with VB (mainly, it will do the conversion from C strings to VB strings for you).
- Build a wrapper DLL, that replicates Lua's interface but using __stdcall, adding the functions that are defined with macros, etc.

I remember that using a custom built Lua, I could register VB functions (defined in modules) into Lua and call them from a script. I don't recall if I ever got it to call member functions.

I hope this can get you started.

Comment: +1. Note that Matt Curland's book "Advanced Visual Basic 6" includes a way to call CDECL DLLs from VB6, but it is to be used with discretion since it adds an overhead to each function call. It might be better to build a custom __stdcall version of this LUA RPG thingy.

Comment: Overhead that is about a string assignment in size and performance :-))

Comment: @wqw: it's true that most of the time the overhead might not be relevant, just like the overhead of a string assignment mostly isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LuaInterface](http://luaforge.net/projects/luainterface/). It's a .NET Library that allows you to use lua. However it doesnt come with docs in and of itself, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339917/luainterface-docs) for some helpful guides.

Basically, you add the DLL to your project and reference it/add using satements, then create a new Lua object. From there, you can access it like an array to extract variables, and there are methods to call lua functions and manipulate tables.

Comment: The question refers to VB 6 not to VB .NET